# How to copy data from docker volume into local system (Windows)

Tags: oracle, docker

I have a running instance of oracle docker image.
And I need to copy its data to use it on another computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'docker cp' command line to achieve this.

**Usage**

> docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH|-
>
> docker cp [OPTIONS] SRC_PATH|- CONTAINER:DEST_PATH

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/ for details.

*Note:* There is a running issue that prevent users to `docker cp` in a Windows mounted volume environment.
Please, see https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34576

Comment: `docker cp dee933f4eb98:/ ./`

Comment: chtimes C:\Users\oleh.kir\dock_im\dev\agpgart: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Oh ok, it seems to be related to an open issue on Windows system, sadly. I edit my previous answer to add this information.